# How do i Snap an vertex just where it touches and edge following it´s own axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I want to slide this vertex, along it´s own axis, till it touches the next edge, and snap to it. I can´t seem to use the snap tool to snap on an edge, following a weird axis that is not X, Y or Z.

That can be easily done in Sketchup, but in Blender I feel like I'm in hell.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender has very limited precision modelling or CAD-like features, this is not natively supported at the moment.

You may look into third party addons to help you achieve this, some are commercial some are free:

- You can try [Blender TinyCAD](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD) addon (which I believe is shipped with Blender by default) that has a few intersection options. It doesn't directly provide snapping options, but can extend an existing edge until it reaches another one.
- If you don't mind spending a little money, there is a payed addon [Snap Utilities](https://blendermarket.com/products/snap-utilities) that provides a Sketchup-like workflow, with a pencil tool. (I am not in any way affiliated or associated with the addon creator, although I did purchase it).
- There is also a [free version of the above Snap Utilities](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?363859-Addon-CAD-Snap-Utilities), with some limitations in functionality